# Why does bash short curcuit fail in crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

If I in a terminal do

```
[ $(/usr/bin/date +"%Y%m%d") -le 20171209 ] && echo aaa >> /tmp/a
```

it it works. If I in `crontab -e`

```
* * * * *   echo aaa >> /tmp/a
```

then it also works. But if I in `crontab -e`

```
* * * * *   [ $(/usr/bin/date +"%Y%m%d") -le 20171209 ] && echo aaa >> /tmp/a
```

then nothing happens.

Looking at `/var/log/cron` I see

```
Sep 12 08:36:01 enote CROND[8809]: (root) CMD ([ $(/usr/bin/date +")
```

**Question**

Can anyone explain what the issue is?

Comment: Most variations of cron use `/bin/sh`, not `bash` (your crontab could call a bash script, but should not rely upon bash features in the crontab itself).

Comment: @ThomasDickey If I first `sh` in a terminal and then `[ $(/usr/bin/date +"%Y%m%d") -le 20171209 ] && echo aaa` then it works, so I don't think it is a sh/bash issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

percent sign has a special meaning in crontab, must be escaped `\%`

`man 5 crontab` `/percent`

```
Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as  standard input.
```